# How to set witdh of hover effect - chart andt Grouped column

Tags: charts, antd

I use Grouped column line chart of Antd.

The default width of the hover effect is wider than the width of 2 columns.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk35Y.png)

I searched and couldn't find a method to edit the width of the hover effect. I would like it to have a width that fits the width of 2 columns like the attached image (up to 2 black lines wide).
Look forward to the help.